# What is the best way to add a Dart hello world into my existing Node.js website?

Tags: html, dart

I have been reading tutorials and guides concerning this but have not found a straight forward answer to this.

I currently have an existing website running on a node.js platform, locally on my computer.

**Goal: Now I want to try and write a simple hello world in Dart, export it to plain JavaScript and see it work in my existing website.**

Reading the documents, I read that I should create a new "Web Application" and to create some sample code up and running, I check the "Generate sample content" box.

[image]

And my project is now created in Dart Editor:

[image]

I can run the sample in Dartium, see it work, etc.

But the problem is that I have now a .html file in the Dart-project, while I have a real .html file for my existing node website in a totally different path. I don't want that. I want to try and use the existing .html instead, since.. thats my real website.

But when trying to create a new Dartium launcher, I can only refer to .html files within my Dart-project:

[image]

So my big question is; How do actually start using Dart with my existing developed website?

How do I create that bridge?

Comment: You generate the .js file(s) and add them to your existing HTML file. Or did I get the question wrong?

Answer (score 1):

On the second image above in your original question, there is an option just below the `HTML file`, called `URL` - is this what you're looking for?  You can set that to any arbitrary URL.

You'd also need to copy the `helloworld.dart` file into your node.js server path, and copy the bits inside the `<body>` tag into your existing HTML page.   You'll also need to copy the `packages\browser\dart.js` file somewhere to your node.js server, too.
If you wanted to run the JS version, you'd also need to use the editor menu option to `Generate JavaScript` and copy the .js files into your node.js server path.

The `script` tag that refers to dart.js automatically detects if the browser supports Dart natively, and will either load the `.dart` version of your app, or the `.dart.js` version of your app (from the same folder location).

So what you're likely after is something like:

```
c:/nodejs_server_root
    /existingIndex.html  // containing the two script tags from helloworld.html 
                         // and other tags referred to in helloworld.dart
    /helloworld.dart
    /dart.js
    /helloworld.dart.js
```

And in the "URL" path in the launch configuration, you'd put something like `http://localhost:<port>/existingIndex.html`

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dev_compiler can compile Dart to Node.js modules with the `--modules=node` option.

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/dev_compiler/issues/291#issuecomment-176687849